# Concurrent.futures ThreadPoolExecutor order

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

I was wondering whether using multiprocessing via:

```py
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=16) as executor:
    results = executor.map(function, iterable)
```

preserves the order of the `iterable`. So if I have `iterable = [0,1]`, the result will be ordered as `result = [function(0), function(1)]`.

If not are there ways to maintain the order, while using a multiprocessing library?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, [`Executor.map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.map) preserves order. [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module also contains [`Pool.map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map), [`Pool.map_async()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map_async) and [`Pool.imap()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap) functions which preserve order.